# TextField.bindAutoCompletion returning object ID

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, controlsfx

I have the following code which build a combobox of states. The code works as expected however I can not get auto complete to work correctly. It appears that the autocomplete is returning object id's instead of the expected text. Clicking on the drop down shows the correct abbreviated state names. Where am I going wrong?

```html
private void buildStateCombo() {
        List<StatesDTO> states = GetStateList.getStatesList();
        StateCombo.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(states));
        StateCombo.setEditable(true);
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(StateCombo.getEditor(), StateCombo.getItems());

        /**
         *  StringConverter
         */
        StateCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<StatesDTO>() {
            
            @Override
            public String toString(StatesDTO object) {
                if (object == null){
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return object.getStateShort();
                }
              }

         
            @Override
            public StatesDTO fromString(String string) {
                return DriverAddStateCombo.getItems().stream().filter(state -> 
                    state.getStateShort().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
            }
        });
}
```

GetStateList look like this...

```html
public class GetStateList {

    public static List<StatesDTO> getStatesList() {
        Database db = new Database();
        List<StatesDTO> statesList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String query = "SELECT stateID, stateCode FROM States";
            ResultSet statesRS = db.executeQuery(query);
            while(statesRS.next()) {
                StatesDTO statesdto = new StatesDTO();
                statesdto.setStateID(statesRS.getString(1));
                statesdto.setStateShort(statesRS.getString(2));
                statesList.add(statesdto);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        db.closeConnection();
        
        return statesList;
    }

}
```

And StatesDTO

```html
public class StatesDTO {
    public SimpleStringProperty stateID = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty stateShort = new SimpleStringProperty();
        
    public String getStateID() {
        return stateID.get();
    }

    public void setStateID(String stateIDStr) {
        stateID.set(stateIDStr);
    }
    
    public String getStateShort() {
        return stateShort.get();
    }

    public void setStateShort(String stateShortStr) {
        stateShort.set(stateShortStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I could make this work to provide the names directly in a collection.

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(StateCombo.getEditor(), 
    StateCombo.getItems().stream().map(state -> 
    state.getStateShort()).collect(Collectors.toList()) );
```

I tried different signatures of the method, such as

[bindAutoCompletion(TextField textField, Callback> suggestionProvider, StringConverter converter)](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.html#bindAutoCompletion-javafx.scene.control.TextField-javafx.util.Callback-javafx.util.StringConverter-)

but I couldn't make it work.

Note: ControlsFX version 8.40.12.